Broken behavior for unmerged tag synonym when there's no questions with target tag
Here on MSE I found the tag that has a synonym but the there's no questions with target tag. That's how it look on tag synonyms page:



On mouse over you can see the tooltip "This tag does not currently exist.". On touch screen devices there is no such hint. You can't just tap that tag because there's no link at all. You need to use source tag, e.i. full-site, instead. But when you do this you'll be redirected to desktop-view tag as the target tag and will see ... zero active questions, however expected count was 14 (as stated next to "full-site" tag).
I think that the full list of full-site questions could be found with SEDE somehow, but I found one manually: The in-review-queues edit layout is different from the normal (out-of-review-queues) edit layout on mobile. How can I always use the former?
Just try to click on "full-site" tag over it to see that there's no such questions.

This is what I get from SEDE for the tag full-site. I used a query from an answer here: Is there a way (e.g. with SEDE) to find questions with an existing tag that's been synonymized (but not merged) into another tag?

I tried to check in SEDE whether there are other synonyms whether the target tag does no exist. I get only thins one on this site. SEDE returns 83 on SO,
